# How should I store a variable so that it be used in different calls of VBA code in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a password authentication step when anyone opens the workbook. I have multiple users who will be accessing this workbook and based on that i have assigned a variable called *user* to identify who amongst them is using it.

```
Public pwd, user As String
Public graccess As Integer

Private Sub workbook_open()
graccess = 0
Do
pwd = InputBox("Please provide your password", "Authentication")
If pwd = "access" Then
    user = "GTS"
    graccess = 1
ElseIf pwd = "enter" Then
    user = "AP"
    graccess = 1
Else
    MsgBox ("failed to authenticate")
    pwd = ""
    graccess = 0
End If
Loop Until graccess = 1
End Sub
```

Now when this user starts working on the excel sheet i need to check the *user* variable to check which user is accessing the sheet. Since this code will now come in the *worksheet_change* event it is a different sub routine which will be run after the previous code has finished running and is out of use.

so my questions are
am i not able to see the user in the variable because my workbook_open event is over and the code has stopped running?
what can i do to make sure the variable does not lose its value?

thanks for the patience :)

Comment: Why not add `msgbox "Current user is:" & user` to your `worksheet_change()` event and see?

Comment: i want to control the access to different parts of the sheet for different users and therefore i need to ascertain who is using it. if user A is using it but wants to modify users B's work area it could be a disaster... basically i cant ASK the user about who he is.. i need to make sure.. any other ideas on how to do it?

Comment: also I cant ask the user for his details everytime he changes something. that could be pretty annoying

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. fix the DIM's

   Dim pwd as string, user as string
2. move the DIM's to a standard module

Answer (score 0):

Store the current username in a `Name` variable in the workbook.

First, add a `Name` to the wokrbook. From the `Formulas` ribbon, do this:

[image]

This is essentially a "variable" that persists after runtime.

In your `Workbook_Open` event handler, do this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names("username") = Environ("username")
```

This uses the system environment variable called "username" which is probably preferable than *asking* for a username, since there's no opportunity to enter the wrong name, whether by accident or maliciously.

Alternatively, you could use an `InputBox` to prompt for a username:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names("username") = Application.InputBox("Please enter your username", "Username", "enter your username")
```

Or, any other method which defines the `Name` as a string value.

Later on, in any of your code modules or event handlers, you can always refer back to the `Name` and then do your validations that way.

Comment: Hi david, thanks for the suggestion. it seems like a good method to do it but i am unable to use it correctly.

Comment: Hi david, thanks for the suggestion. it seems like a good method to do it but i am unable to use it correctly. when i write ActiveWorkbook.Names("username")= "GTS" or alternatively try and pick a value from a string variable it gives me a compile time error "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" . i have been trying to understand why this is happening but havent been able to. could you please help me out with this?

Comment: Did you create the name first? You could get an error if you had not created the name.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code you are attempting to use? I would maybe expect a `1004` error if the name is not yet established. I can try to troubleshoot your particular error.